# Where can I find the code for the Stanford CoreNLP dependency tree visualizer?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Where can I find the code for the [Stanford CoreNLP dependency tree visualizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/)?

I've found it to be an extremely useful tool, however I've also found it to be frequently offline (like it is right now).  I'd like to host a personal instance so I don't have to deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, the code for the tangent project 'corenlp.run' for visualising the dependency tree is hosted on github at https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP.

To run your own instance, simply run the command:

`java -mx4g -cp "<stanford-corenlp-folder>/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer`

This will start a server at your http://localhost:9000/ by default.

Answer (score 3):

The visualization tool we use is [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/).

If you're referring to the actual form code as well, I don't believe we have a supported open-source release of that code. It should be easy to replicate, though, with a makeshift Java web app.

Comment: You're right, though I was hoping to not have spend the time to do that.